# Gradle taking time up front seemingly doing nothing

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx, kotlin

Gradle seem to be really slow for me and I have no idea why.
Whenever I run a build it takes like 30 seconds for me, according to the output 25 seconds of those it's doing nothing.

Building like this:

```
gradlew build --parallel --offline
```

This is happening to me now with Kotlin, it was the same when I was using Java only, incremental builds don't seem to do anything either

EDIT: I have the gradle daemon enabled

Every subsequent build right at the start takes as long or longer than starting the daemon apparently doing nothing

This is my Project: https://github.com/forsakenharmony/GameProt

Comment: Can you share your build output?

Comment: http://hastebin.com/ezebosakon.vbs

It takes 20 seconds before outputting the first line

Comment: Try run gradle in debug mode `-d` and examine the output to check what's going on when _nothing happens_.

Comment: Check your ip4 vs. ip6 is configured correctly on your machine, sometimes something with network access can stall on the JVM for like 20-30 seconds due to that.  If you debug with Intellij you will see the same pause at start of debugging.

Comment: stalling right after this `01:32:50.151 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.services.NativeServices] Native-platform posix files is not available.  Continuing with fallback.`

Comment: here's the full log  
https://files.debugspeople.com/gradle/gradle.log

Answer (score 1):

I recommend starting with some measurement:

```
gradlew build --profile
```

Open up /report/profile in a web browser and see what it's doing.

It sounds to me like your project is taking a long time to configure. Do you have a large project or many projects in your build? Are you using a bunch of plugins?

The easy way to reduce configuration time is to configure fewer things. Remove plugins that you only use rarely. Try out the `@Incubating` `--configure-on-demand` option.

Come back after you've confirmed via profiling for further help.

Comment: that's the profile, 1m20.68s / 1m31.10s is startup time

Answer (score 0):

You can try enabling [gradle daemon](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html). 
That way gradle won't have to load from scratch every time you start a build. Instead, it will run in background waiting for a build to start.

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

in «USER_HOME»/.gradle/gradle.properties

Comment: I have the daemon enabled by default, it seems like my PC is just strange